# Unable to set custom field value on the chat transcript object from pre-chat using Embedded Service

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, chat, pre-chat, livechattranscript

I am using an embedded service deployment to show a chat window on a publicly hosted webpage. This chat has a pre-chat form configured where I take in the contact details. I want to input some additional fields like subject and message from the user and store it in a custom field on the LiveChatTranscript Object record. The reason I am using a custom field instead of storing it directly on the Case is so that I can decide from the subject if there is an existing case that I should attach to the chat, or should I create a new Case.

Here is the code I am using for storing custom field Subject:

```
embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [
    {
        "label": "Case Subject",
        "transcriptFields": ["CaseSubject__c"],
        "displayToAgent":true
    }
];
```

Even after adding this code, I am just seeing the FirstName, LastName, and Email fields which I have configured in the Pre-chat page and not this additional subject field.

I also need to confirm where actually we need to write this code and if I am missing anything.

Comment: did you managed to figure this out? I have a similar issue, the settings js don't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to update the "value" attribute for the field like below

```
embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [
{
    "label": "Case Subject",
    "transcriptFields": ["CaseSubject__c"],
    "displayToAgent":true,
    "value": "Subject for the case"
}];
```

It's the value attribute that is mapped to the field

Answer (score 0):

May be this link can help.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000349323&type=1

small Extract from the link:

> If you want to save dynamic values from the pre-chat form directly
> into a custom field in the transcript object.
>
> - Create a custom field on the transcript object (for example,    PrechatText__c).
> - Pass the transcript fields in the extra pre-chat form details without    passing the value property.
>
>   embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{"label":"Text", "transcriptFields": ["PrechatText__c"]}];
>
> ....